# How to call html inside of the tempate using webpy (2.7)

Tags: html, python-2.7, templates, web.py

I'm trying to learn how to recreate a website using web.py, but am having trouble finding the syntax I need.

In every other language I've used, including pure HTML, there is a way to render html in a webpage by calling a script, object, package, or a view to keep things somewhat modular.  So how do I do this with Python?

I'd be fine rearranging all the non-layout files to the static directory, rewriting them as Python files that write and return the HTML somehow, or including the sub files in the url handling if there is a way to access and load them to the html that way.

I was hoping to call a .py to run a script which would write or call the html I need for that section, but I can't seem to find examples that meet my needs.

Thanks in advance, for any suggestions.

now my code looks something like:
code.py

```
import web

urls = (
    '/favicon.ico', 'icon',
    '/', 'index',
    '/index', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)
render = web.template.render('templates/')#, base='Layout')
static = web.template.render('static/')
Main = web.template.render('templates/')
MainContent = web.template.render('Content/')

class static:
    def GET(self):
        return static()

class icon:
    def GET(self):
        return static.favicon()

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return Main.Layout(0, 0, 'Main.css')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

/templates/Layout.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="static/$vCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="idBody">
    <table id="idTableMain">
        <tr id="idHeaderRow">
            <td id="idHeaderRowCenter" colspan="3">
                 <img src="static/logo.jpg"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="idNavigationRow">
            <td id="idNavigationBar" colspan="3">
                 <!--Display /templates/NavBar.html -->
            </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr id="idCenterRow">
            <td id="idCenterRowLeft">
                <h4>
                    Navigation
                </h4>
                <!--Display /templates/Navigation.html -->

            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowMain">
                <!--Display /templates/Content/Content_index.html -->
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowRight">
                <h4>
                    Information
                </h4>
                This was written with Python.<br><br>
                Other versions of this page are here:<br>
                <!--Display /templates/Versions_index.html -->   
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="idFooterRow">
            <td id="idFooterMain" colspan="3">
                <!--Display /templates/Footer.html -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow the examples available with web.py documentation, then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: the ones I have found don't cover this.  they skip ahead to databases.

Comment: I feel this is a specific enough question, and is something obvious and simple for you all that know web.py and python well.

I'm just a little green and could use some guidance to how to do this right instead of trying to just put all the code into variables and passing that in on the main .py file......unless that's the answer.

Comment: Okay, then my answer is use web.py Templates. Put your parameters in variables and pass them into Templates which can do the rendering.

Comment: I was able to write some of the html I need on page in the main .py file to pass through a variable as you were saying.

It honestly didn't occur to me do it that way as it feels very different than other languages.  I'm sure I'll be able to break it up into modules to import for readability eventually.

@pbuck if you can please state that a little more clearly in an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.

Comment: Not sure we're on the same page yet... What do you want to pass into Layout.html? In your python, you're passing three parameters `(0, 0, 'Main.css')`. But, your provided `Layout.html` doesn't accept any parameters: it should start with `$def with(a, b, c)`. Within the Layout file, you can programmatically write more HTML with loops, and other python control structures. And/Or, you can pass in already created HTML as "text" and have your Layout.html merely print it (as `$:my_html`).

Comment: apologies, I should have kept that line in the layout.html, just got lost in the shuffle.

I think there are a few different ways to do this, but the way I'm currently proceeding is that I'm building the html for each section of the Layout in python modules, importing that into my main .py file, and passing the string from the class to the layout as an argument, finally loading it as a variable.

Comment: Another way, you're saying, is to call the build function directly on the Layout, but in order to call the navigation correctly, I'd either have to use the same system for the hierarchy, which means their is no point in moving where its called, or I could rearrange everything so its all laid relatively.

That would mean having more granular control on Layouts level by level, but having a more files to manage. I'll probably have to play with it a bit.  Either I'm going to change this or the rest of my sites to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've learned a little and am now able to replicate my site in web.py, BUT I don't like how I'm doing it in certain places.

1) I want to be able to call the templates without calling Main each time.
2) I want to be able to call the functions from the Layout.

Please comment if you like, any advice to the above would be helpful.

I'll be copying this and reposting as another question as well.

code.py:

```
import web
import Universal
import Navigation
import Content
import Versions


urls = (
    '/favicon.ico', 'icon',
    '/', 'index',
    '/Section1/index', 'Section1',
    '/Section2/index', 'Section2',
    '/Section3/index', 'Section3'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)
render = web.template.render('templates/')#, base='Layout')

static = web.template.render('static/')

Main = web.template.render('templates/')
Section1 = web.template.render('templates/Section1/')
Section2 = web.template.render('templates/Section2/')
Section3 = web.template.render('templates/Section3/')

class static:
    def GET(self):
        return static()

#class icon:
#    def GET(self):
#        return static.favicon()

class index:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '0'
        vSection = '0'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section1:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '1'
        vSection = '1'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Section1.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section2:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '2'
        vSection = '2'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Section2.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section3:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '3'
        vSection = '3'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        #return render.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)
        return Main.Section3.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)
```

templates/Layout.html:

```
$def with (vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

<html>
<head>
    $:vHead
</head>
<body id="idBody">
    <table id="idTableMain">
        <tr id="idHeaderRow">
            <td id="idHeaderRowCenter" colspan="3">
                $:vHeader
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="idNavigationRow">
            <td id="idNavigationBar" colspan="3">
                $:vNavBar
            </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr id="idCenterRow">
            <td id="idCenterRowLeft">
                <h4>
                    Navigation
                </h4>
                $:vNavigation
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowMain">
                $:vContent
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowRight">
                <h4>
                    Information
                </h4>
                This was written with Python 2.7 and web.py.<br><br>
                Other versions of this page are here:<br>
                $:vVersions
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="idFooterRow">
            <td id="idFooterMain" colspan="3">
                $:vFooter
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Universal.py

```
def getHead(vSection):
    vResult = '<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">'
    vResult += '<link href=' + getCSS(vSection) + ' rel=\"stylesheet\" type="text/css">'
    return vResult

def getCSS(vSection):
    if vSection == '1':
        vResult = '/static/Section1/Section1.css'
    elif vSection == '2':
        vResult = '/static/Section2/Section2.css'
    elif vSection == '3':
        vResult = '/static/Section3/Section3.css'
    else:
        vResult = '/static/Main.css'
    return vResult

def getHeader():
    vResult = '<img id=\"idLogo\" src=' + getLogo() + '>'
    return vResult
def getNavBar():
    vResult = '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/index\'>Home</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section1/index\'>Web Programming</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section2/index\'>Private Projects</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section3/index\'>Downloadable Projects</a>'
    return vResult
```